# ST_3DIntersects says 'no' despite geometries intersecting

Tags: postgis, 3d, geos, sfcgal

Considering the following query I expect both `geomb` and `geomc` to 3D Intersect with `geoma`. According to postgis, only geomc intersects. Unfortunately I can't come up with a more simplified polygon as an example, this situation seems largely to depend on the configuration of the polygon.

```
WITH data AS (
SELECT 
ST_SetSrid(ST_GeometryFromText('
POLYGON Z ((
    122409.416 489410.194 6.64975853832649,
    122404.759 489412.266 3.76021877729423,
    122407.18 489417.708 3.82360012934401,
    122405.377 489418.511 2.70471051793069,
    122406.754 489421.606 2.74081838637221,
    122408.218 489420.954 3.64933000361367,
    122409.263 489423.303 3.67668436361495,
    122407.787 489423.959 2.76102260948305,
    122409.313 489427.389 2.80101513611236,
    122411.091 489426.598 3.90419939305872,
    122411.172 489426.781 3.9061156669998,
    122409.45 489427.547 2.83769648670792,
    122410.905 489430.819 2.87547799988339,
    122412.594 489430.067 3.92357220158512,
    122413.511 489432.131 3.94697470225165,
    122411.723 489432.926 2.83768486408258,
    122413.229 489436.312 2.87694266543155,
    122414.931 489435.555 3.93292998257874,
    122415.345 489436.484 3.94412204281057,
    122420.157 489434.343 6.9298432176791,
    122409.416 489410.194 6.64975853832649
))
'),28992) as geoma,


ST_Extrude(ST_SetSrid(ST_GeometryFromText('
LINESTRING Z (
    122412.982 489429.097 0,
    122414.559 489432.685 0
)
'),28992),0,0,10) as geomb,
ST_Extrude(ST_SetSrid(ST_GeometryFromText('
LINESTRING Z (
    122414.559 489432.685 0,
    122412.756 489433.477 0
)
'),28992),0,0,10) as geomc
)


SELECT 
ST_3DIntersects(geoma,geomb) ab,
ST_3DIntersects(geoma,geomc) ac
FROM data;
```

Results in: 
`f;t`

Would this be a bug in postgis/geos/sfcgal?

**Please note:** the given geoma above is non-planar because of rounding when exporting to text. In the database it shows `ST_IsPlanar(geoma)` as `true` and gives the same results. On top of that, in the database running  `ST_3DIntersection` on geoma vs. geomb and geoma vs. geomc both give a good result. This is not replicable here because of non-planarity.

The situation is perhaps better described in this picture, where geoma is blue, geomb is red and geomc is green. The geometries in the image have been Tesselated for display purpose only.

[image]

Comment: It's a very good question. The 3D stuff is very hard to debug, but I agree with you, both ought to be true, as they intersect in 2d and you have extruded by 10 in the z direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the bug has been corrected. I had a try and got result `true,true`with this PostGIS version:

```
POSTGIS="3.4.1 3.4.1" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="160" GEOS="3.12.1-CAPI-1.18.1" SFCGAL="SFCGAL 1.5.0, CGAL 5.6, BOOST 1.78.0" PROJ="8.2.1
```

Comment: Hadn't looked at this for a loong time but can confirm that in SFCGAL 1.4.1 this is also solved.